# Why can we remove the absolute value from $\ln$ when exponentiating both sides?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In my calculus 2 class, the professor had the following equation:

$\ln|x|=y$

Then he took the exponent of both sides to get $x = e^y$.  But isn't this wrong? Shouldn't it instead be $|x|=e^y$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the  conclusion ought to be $ \vert x \vert = e^y$, or (equivalently) $ x = \pm e^y$.

Based on the context and my own experience, I suspect that somewhere in your professor's exposition there was an arbitrary constant $C$.  If you actually have $\ln \vert x \vert = y + C$, then when you exponentiate you get $\vert x \vert = A e^y$, or $x = \pm A e^y$, where $A = e^C$ is an arbitrary positive constant.  (Do you see why $A$ has to be positive?) This can then be rewritten as $ x = B e^y$, where $B$ is *any* constant (not necessarily positive).

Informally, it is okay to "drop" the absolute value sign because the ambiguity of the sign can be absorbed into the constant coefficient.  But I agree that this should have been made explicit.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed wrong. As a counterexample, suppose that $x=-e$ and $y=1$. Then since $\ln e=1$, the first equation holds, but we have $e^1=e\neq-e$.